# Compare dataframe value with key range in dictionary and return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm trying to compare a value in a dataframe with key ranges in a dictionary and grab the corresponding dictionary value.
Been looking at loop and iterations, however, as a beginner, can't get it working.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

colors = {range(0,50):"red",range(50,100):"blue",
          range(100,150):"green",range(150,200):"orange"
          ,range(200, 250):"purple", range(250,1000):"grey"}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[51,8,265,167], columns=['A'])
```

The result I'm looking for:

```
    A     color
0   51    blue
1   8     red
2   265   grey
3   167   orange
```

This is my basic idea (used a hard coded value):

```
for (start, end), value in colors.items():
    if start <= 85 < end:
        print(value) #add retrieved value to dataframe
```

I guess I could use a comprehension and/or a lambda function but again, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

You can vectorise your calculation using [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). This will be more efficient, and easier to maintain, than a loopy `if` / `else` construct.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

colors = {range(0,50):"red",range(50,100):"blue",
          range(100,150):"green",range(150,200):"orange",
          range(200, 250):"purple", range(250,1000):"grey"}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[51,8,265,167], columns=['A'])

df['color'] = np.select([df['A'].isin(x) for x in colors], colors.values(), None)
```

**Result**

```
     A   color
0   51    blue
1    8     red
2  265    grey
3  167  orange
```